# Lost password of sata disk

Tags: hard-drive, security, passwords, sata

a customer of me lost his password of a secured sata disk (Seagate). I read that SATA has a security extension which disables the disk by the controller after some wrong attempts. I also read that this security extension can be bypassed or disabled with a master password. A tried some tools of Hiren´s boot cd but I was not able to disable the password.

Are there any other options or tutorials that I can try?

Comment: It would be nice if you added links for "I read that". Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some hard disk firmwares that lockout will have limited password attempts, and may lock permanently after several failed attempts.

I had this experience with an older Hitachi PATA, luckily the customer did not have any pertinent data on it.

Worst case; You may need to contact Seagate's in-house data recovery division: http://www.seagate.com/services-software/data-recovery-services/consumers/in-lab-data-recovery/process/